# How to write security rules of firebase-Realtimedatabase so unauth user can read and write only at my specific nodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to know how we can write firebase realtime database security rules in the way like unauthenticated user can read and write on a specific nodes only

Right now my security rules are like this

```
 "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
```

my database structure is like this

```
 request
   |-user_id
     |-email:"value"
```

i want that the user can write from my Android app on this node even though he is not logged in using firebase auth

I am developing android app.

```
 "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how we can write firebase realtime database security rules in the way like unauthenticated user can read and write on a specific nodes only

To allow unauthenticated users to read/write data on a specific ("request") section in your database, you should use the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "request": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

For more information, please check the official documentation regarding [authorization on a specific section in Firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-authorization).

Comment: Thank you so much I applied your method and it is working for me